# Is it possible do use data from a different collection inside an aggregation on mongoDB 2.6

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get information from one collection using the data from another collection, because I need the merge information from both collections.

Is it possible to do that?

```html
var Mclient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID
//Connection URL
var url = 'url de conexao'
Mclient.connect(url, function (err, db){
    console.log('Connect correctly to server')
    var notes = db.collection('notes')
var cid = ObjectId("1")
notes.aggregate([
    { $match: {companyId:cid} },
    { $sort: {createdAt: -1}},
    { $unwind: "$users"},
    { $unwind: "$users.tags"},
    { $group: {
            _id: '$_id' ,
            Type: {$addToSet: '$type'},
            ComanyId: {$addToSet: '$companyId'},
            ProjectId: {$addToSet: '$projectId'},
            Priority: {$addToSet: '$Priority'},
            UsersData: {$push: {userId:"$users.userId", userTag: "$users.tags"}},
            CreateDate: {$addToSet: '$createdAt'},
            CompletedDate: {$addToSet: '$completedAt'},
            DeletedDate: {$addToSet: '$deletedAt'},
            total: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }]).each(function(err, doc, db){
        if (doc){

            var notes = db.collection('notes')
            // Find para buscar outros dados usando dados do aggregate realizado acima
            var dataNotes = notes.findOne({ _id: doc.ProjectId[0]})

        }else{
            return null
        }
      if (err) throw err
    })
   db.close()
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. The ability to get data from a different collection ([`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)) was added only in version 3.2.

You *can* do it in two separate queries: first get the notes, then get the users data in a separate query, and join them together in you application.

Or you can upgrade to a newer version of MongoDB...

Comment: Thanks for the help =)